# Fig up: Cannot find module - docker run works

Tags: node.js, docker, fig

I'm trying to run `fig up` with a minimal node app.

(edited: removed volumes from fig.yml)

fig.yml:

```
example:
  build: .
  command: node server.js
  ports:
   - "4000:4000"
  links:
   - postgres
postgres:
  image: postgres
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
```

server.coffee:

```
express = require 'express'
app = express()

app.get "/", (req, res) ->
  res.send "Hello World"

server = app.listen 4000, () ->
  console.log 'Listening on port %d', server.address().port
```

`fig build` proceeds as expected. `fig up` fails with:

```
example_1  | module.js:340
example_1  |     throw err;
example_1  |           ^
example_1  | Error: Cannot find module '/src/server.js'
example_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
example_1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
example_1  |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
example_1  |     at startup (node.js:119:16)
example_1  |     at node.js:906:3
```

What I don't understand is that I can run the server in a container (that fig built) without fig:

```
$ docker run -it dockerexample_example /bin/bash
root@58d25759047a:/# node /src/server.js 
Listening on port 4000
```

Or

```
$ docker run -it dockerexample_example
Listening on port 4000
```

Or

```
$ docker run -it -p 4000:4000 dockerexample_example
Listening on port 4000
```

What is different about the way fig is trying to run this container?

These files are available here: https://github.com/skyl/docker-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is the `volumes`. In the `docker run`  examples you aren't specifying any volumes, but in your `fig.yml` you are mounting the current working directory to `/src` in the container, so the `/src` that was added during build is masked by the volume, and the node_modules are not available.

I think you should be fine to remove the `volumes` from the `fig.yml`, otherwise you'll have to run the npm install outside of the container as well.

Comment: Note that I had to forcibly `docker rmi` the bad images, it seems.

Comment: `fig up` currently has an issue with changes to volumes definition https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/447